# How to obtain the elasticity from a log-level regression

Tags: regression, inference

I have forgotten my undergrad econometrics, and was hoping that someone could help to refresh my memory.

If I have a regression $\ln y=a+bX+e$, and want to evaluate the elasticity of $y$ with respect to $X$ (at the mean of $X$), how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the elasticity using the formula

$elasticity=\frac{dy}{dx} \frac{x}{y}$

In your case (assuming e is the error so we can ignore it)

$y = e^{a+bx}=e^ae^{bx}$ (after applying the exponential function to both sides)

And then $\frac{dy}{dx}=be^ae^{bx}$

Plugging that into the formula gives

$elasticity=be^ae^{bx}\frac{x}{y}=\frac{be^ae^{bx}x}{e^ae^{bx}}=bx$